# What is the right way to restart WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I want to restart my WPF Application programmitically; in windows Forms I used
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();

I have tried this :

```
private void Restart() 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ResourceAssembly.Location); 
    Application.Current.Shutdown(); 
}
```

I have deployed my application with ClickOnce and its not working there. 
Any help would be great.

Comment: But it does work locally?

Comment: @rene Yes it works locally.

Comment: @Sayse It is not the correct duplicate. The issue is being deployed with ClickOnce which isn't addressed in that particular duplicate...

Comment: @rene - In which case [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5291937/1324033) was another google search away, In particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15618333/1324033)

Comment: Ok, will make sure we close against that duplicate @Sayse