# How to run the progress bar externally and handle the loading function internally in an asynchronous manner

Tags: wpf, async-await, task

```
MainWindow.GetInstance.GetVM.Busy("Probe loading", false);    
foreach (var probe in Datas.GetInstance.CurProbeProcessInfo)
{
    var find_center = MainWindow.GetInstance.GetVM.CenterViews.Where(o => o.GetVM.ProbeNum == probe.No).FirstOrDefault();
    if (find_center != null)
    {
        await MainWindow.GetInstance.GetVM.CenterViewBinding(probe);
    }
}
MainWindow.GetInstance.GetVM.UnBusy();


public async Task CenterViewBinding(ProbeCommonSt probe)
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    { 

        if (probe != null)
    {
        Methods.SetMode(probe.Mode);

        var find_center = CenterViews.Where(o => o.GetVM.ProbeNum == probe.No).FirstOrDefault();
        if (find_center != null)
        {
            // Enabled 보다 Mode를 먼저 설정해야함 Enabled 변경 시 
            // U_TabPane_SelectionChanged 이벤트가 터져서 Mode 구분 안됨
            // [ Mode & ParentName 업데이트 ]
            {
                find_center.GetVM.Mode = probe.Mode;
                if (probe.Mode == MODE.SINGLE)
                {
                    find_center.GetVM.ParentName = probe.CurFolder;
                    ModelListView.GetInstance.GetVM.DataBinding(probe);
                }
                else
                    find_center.GetVM.ParentName = Path.GetFileName(probe.DataPath);
            }


            // [ 탭 활성화 ]
            find_center.GetVM.Enabled = true;
            find_center.Activate();
            ActivePane = find_center;


            // [ 정보창 업데이트 ]
            if (probe.No == Datas.MONITORING_NO)
                DisplayMeasureConnditionMonitor(probe);
            else
                DisplayMeasureConnditionProbe(probe);


            // [해당 모드의 measure setting menu header binding]
            m_view.U_TitleBar.GetVM.DataBinding();


            // [측정 탭 활성화에 따른 border color binding]
            find_center.GetVM.DataBinding();


            // [해당 프로브의 data list binding]
            find_center.GetVM.DataList.DataBinding(probe);


            // [프로브 정보 업데이트]
            find_center.GetVM.MeasureAndTime.AssignProbe(probe);


            // [측정 설정에 현재 프로브 데이터 적용]
            find_center.GetVM.MeasureSetting.ApplyProbeSettings(probe);


            // [probe 전환시 싱글모드 데이터 적용]
            UpdateActive(probe, find_center);
        }
    }

    });
}
```

Asynchronously, I would like to display the loading status by running a round progress bar in the UI, and handle binding to various places internally with the loaded data.

I searched various documents and studied synchronous and asynchronous processing, but I have a question because it is difficult to apply it to my case.

In my case, the progress bar does not appear and it loads right away. Also, there is a phenomenon where the UI freezes during the binding process. I want to load naturally without this phenomenon.

Comment: You would implement something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55647791/1136211

Comment: There is a lot of work done on the UI thread during the update process, so even if you use the recommended method, stuttering occurs.