# Distribute application from network share (autostart)

Tags: c#, autostart, network-share

I have an application that I want to share on my company's network share. It's a .exe with some .dll's.

We have ~40 users who will need this program. We want it to autostart with the computer.

The problem rises when we need to update the application. Because some of the users might have the application running we cannot delete the .exe and replace it with a new one...

Some say I should use .NET "ClickOnce", but it would'nt work with autostart, right?

**What would be the best way to do this?** **Have a seperate .exe that copies the application to the users temp-folder and then run it from there?**

Comment: Its a duplicate question check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247439/c-sharp-autostart-automatically-add-application-to-startup-folder and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291937/restart-wpf-application-after-click-once-update-start-the-new-version

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup. I have the exe as `read only`. This way I can replace the .exe and **make it read only again**. When the user restarts the application it has the updated version.

You can set it read only by right clicking -> properties -> check read only.

To auto start it, just add a shortcut to the start up folder.